# How override Cassandra Repository's behaviour in Spring Data to support Insert/update records specifying a TTL

Tags: kotlin, cassandra, spring-data

I'm working on a project where we need to specify the TTL when we insert and update records in a Cassandra database. The idea is not to delete the records but to flag them as *deleted* and specify a short ttl for all columns of "deleted" records. We already specify a default ttl in the schema, but we need to be able to change that ttl on the fly.

The `CassandraRepository`, implemented by `SimpleCassandraRepository`, does not expose this functionality.

Looking at Cassandra Spring Data's documentation [[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html)] I came up with this code below, which complains about a circular reference at runtime:

```kotlin
@NoRepositoryBean
interface ExtendedCassandraRepository<T, ID>: CassandraRepository<T, ID> {
    fun <S> save(entity: S & Any, ttl: Int): S where S: T
}

class ExtendedCassandraRepositoryImpl<T, ID> @Autowired constructor(
    private val entityInformation: CassandraEntityInformation<T, ID>,
    private val operations: CassandraOperations
): SimpleCassandraRepository<T, ID>(entityInformation, operations), ExtendedCassandraRepository<T, ID> {
    override fun <S: T> save(entity: S & Any, ttl: Int): S {
        val insertOptions = InsertOptions.builder().ttl(ttl).build()
        return operations.insert(entity, insertOptions).entity
    }
}

@Qualifier("extRepo")
interface ExtendedTRegCassandraRepository: ExtendedCassandraRepository<TReg, TRegIdPK>

@Repository
@Qualifier("customTRegsRepository")
class ExtendedTRegCassandraRepositoryImpl @Autowired constructor(
    @Qualifier("extRepo")
    base: ExtendedTRegCassandraRepository
) : ExtendedTRegCassandraRepository by base
```

I'm just pretty new to Kotlin, with no prior Spring Boot/Spring Data knowledge. I introduced the `@Qualifier` annotations following hints given by the compiler.

How should I do for creating a customised repository as commented above?

Is there any working example in Kotling that could provide hints on how to proceed?

BR